# Android-studio: how to call method that expects view param from same class?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have a method that can be called by 5 buttons but it should also be called once on startup. How do I pass the view parameter while calling the method from same class?

```
    public void GetFromAPI(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button8:
                call = ApiQuery.getDay();
                MkGraph = 24;
                break;
            case R.id.button9:
                call = ApiQuery.getWeek();
                MkGraph = 7;
                break;
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just send `null` and in the function check if the value is `null` or not and do your action depending on that. Or you can just get the `View` object using `findViewById` & send it to the function.